# got stuck uploading a simple visual studio project to github

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, github

I started a Visual Studio project.

To upload it to GitHub, I ran `git add .` but I got this error:

```
open(".vs/projectdesign/FileContentIndex/362d2a41-e466-4aa4-a3cc-cb6615d99b12.vsidx"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file '.vs/projectdesign/FileContentIndex/362d2a41-e466-4aa4-a3cc-cb6615d99b12.vsidx'
fatal: adding files failed
```

My repository is public if it has anything to do with it and I don't quite understand what the problem is.
When I just try to upload things to github it does give me so it surely means that it is related to the visual studio project.

Comment: You should be using a `.gitignore` file to exclude things that shouldn't be committed, like the `.vs` directory. Here's an example: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/VisualStudio.gitignore

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try add a .gitignore file. Before adding your project to Git, it's a good idea to have a .gitignore file in your project's root directory. This file tells Git which files or directories to ignore when adding or committing changes.

Answer (score 0):

You should  add .gitignore , if you have not .gitignore file you can create this with visual studio